# Access BOSH-lite Cloud Foundry VM from local network

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, paas

I've successfully installed a local instance of Cloud Foundry via Bosh-lite (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/README.md).

I can use and access CF from the local machine without problems.
However, I cannot access CF from another machine in the local network.

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The standard BOSH-Lite setup requires you to add a route to your iptables so that requests to Cloud Foundry components (with `10.244.0.0/16` IPs) running in the BOSH-Lite VM can be reached directly using the BOSH-Lite VM (whose IP defaults to `192.168.50.4`) as a gateway. Check out Step 5 of the [setup instructions](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite#using-the-virtualbox-provider).

You would need to:

1. make the BOSH-Lite VM accessible to other machines on the network, and,
2. configure the other machines to route requests for `10.244.0.0/16` to the accessible address of the BOSH-Lite VM.